# Loopback throws errors Unprocessable Entity

Tags: vue.js, loopback

I am using vue js for front end development and i am using loopback api for backend . When I make the request form loopback api ,it works fine but when I tried to insert data from webpage I got following errors in console window.

**HTMLPage2.html:101 POST http://localhost:3000/api/Cat/ 422 (Unprocessable 
Entity)**

Here is my code .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <script src="./server.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>





</head>
<body>

  <div id="catApp">

    <h1>Cats</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Breed</th>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="cat in cats">
          <td @click="editCat(cat)" class="catItem" title="Click to Edit">{{cat.name}}</td>
          <td>{{cat.age}}</td>
          <td>{{cat.gender}}</td>
          <td>{{cat.breed}}</td>
          <td @click="deleteCat(cat)" class="deleteCat" title="Click to Delete">Delete</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <form @submit.prevent="storeCat">
      <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" v-model="cat.name">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="number" id="age" v-model="cat.age">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="breed">Breed</label>
        <input type="text" id="breed" v-model="cat.breed">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
        <input type="text" id="gender" v-model="cat.gender">
      </p>
      <input type="reset" value="Clear" @click="reset">
      <input type="submit" value="Save Cat ">
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    const API = 'http://localhost:3000/api/Cat/';
    let catApp = new Vue({
      el: '#catApp',
      data: {
        cats: [],
        cat: {
          id: '',
          name: '',
          age: '',
          gender: '',
          breed: ''
        }
      },
      created: function () {
        this.getCats();
      },
      methods: {
        getCats: function () {
          fetch(API)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => this.cats = res);
        },
        storeCat: function () {
          let method;
          console.log('storeCat', this.cat);
          // Handle new vs old
          if (this.cat.id === '') {
            delete this.cat.id;
            method = 'POST';
          } else {
            method = 'PUT';
          }
          fetch(API, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: method,
            body: JSON.stringify(this.cat)
          })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
              this.getCats();
              this.reset();
            });
        },
        deleteCat: function (c) {
          fetch(API + c.id, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'DELETE'
          })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
              this.getCats();
            });

          // call reset cuz the cat could be 'active'
          this.reset();
        },
        editCat: function (c) {
          /*
          This line was bad as it made a reference, and as you typed, it updated
          the list. A user may think they don't need to click save.
          this.cat = c;
          */
          this.cat.id = c.id;
          this.cat.name = c.name;
          this.cat.age = c.age;
          this.cat.breed = c.breed;
          this.cat.gender = c.gender;
        },
        reset: function () {
          this.cat.id = '';
          this.cat.name = '';
          this.cat.age = '';
          this.cat.breed = '';
          this.cat.gender = '';
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the screen shot of the error .
[image: click]

Answer (score 0):

422 (Unprocessable Entity) means you make a validation on the data request
and failed or you try insert data directly to database but error occurred cause of data is null and your column not allow null or something else..

so insure your data is correct 
If you click the last link in console like in the image ,you will see in network data the response of your request

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following steps :

1)Just update your API endpoint as 'http://localhost:3000/api/Cats/'.

2)refresh your html file.